# Role of a Class in Java

Tags: java, class, object, methods

I am going through some past exam papers and some questions are pretty basic. One of the Question is;

which of the following best describes the role of a class in the Java language?
a) A class defines where a Java program starts executing.
b) A class is a graphical user interface component.
c) A class is a specification of an object, through grouping variables and methods that define that object.
d) A class is an instance of an object containing variables and methods.
e) A class is a group of IT students in the Computing Building at the university.

I personally believe that it's 'C' but then again 'D' also seems like the role of a class(my apologies if i am wrong). I am new to Java so i'm sorry if this seems like an unprofessional question. Thanks for your help.

Comment: The correct answer is C. A class is not an instance of an object. Rather, an object is an instance of a class. (However, there's something to be said for answer E, particularly if it's a class on Java.)

Comment: Re: d) ... the "explanation" is the wrong way around.  "An object is an instance of a class which defines the variables and methods".

Answer (score 2):

The answer here is C.

Think of class as a blueprint for an object.
That is, if you are building a house, you're going to have a blueprint for it. The blueprint is the class, and the house is the object.

The class will also have "appropriate" and relevant fields and methods.
For example, if you have a class named Apple, you don't want to have a method something like getHorsePower.

Answer (score 1):

> A class is a specification of an object, through grouping variables
>   and methods that define that object.

And, basically, it's a blue print of it's objects.

Answer (score 0):

a) A class defines where a Java program starts executing.
INCORRECT: It depends on where main() is located.

b) A class is a graphical user interface component.
INCORRECT: To create GUI multiple classes are required.

c) A class is a specification of an object, through grouping variables and methods that define that object.
CORRECT:

d) A class is an instance of an object containing variables and methods.
INCORRECT: Object is an instance of class not vice versa.

e) A class is a group of IT students in the Computing Building at the university. 
INCORRECT: Unrelated to Java